# Disable bash completion of asterisk when ambiguos

Tags: bash, tab-completion

My bash is autocompleting filenames in an unexpected way. I have a directory with 2 files:

```
$ ls
ssh-8ZwoymYvfDSu ssh-ha7JCIFmjUKR
```

When entering some prefix of the name and pressing `<tab>`, bash completes until the point where the 2 names differ (which is expected):

```
$ ls ss
$ ls ssh-
```

However when I add an asterisk after the prefix and press `<tab>`, bash completes to one of the filenames (even though the prefix is ambiguous, bash ignores all other files):

```
$ ls ss*
$ ls ssh-8ZwoymYvfDSu
```

I was looking at the documentation, but didn't find anything useful. I have currently set the following variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
bind 'set colored-completion-prefix on'
bind 'set match-hidden-files off'
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
```

I would like bash to only complete an asterisk if the name is not ambiguous. How can I do that?

Comment: If there is no ambiguity why do you need an asterisk, and if you put an asterisk why to you use tab completion? What you describe seems to be the standard behavior and despite my heavy use of auto-completion I hadn't noticed this until now...  Also considered what should happen if you have a file with an asterisk in the name: the asterisk is handled as a regular character by the auto-completion.

Comment: @xenoid Let's say I want to delete a bunch of files which are named `temp*`. Before pressing enter, I use tab to make sure the files matching are exactly the ones I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the package bash-completion fixed the issue.

Comment: Seems like overkill. The package provides more than the mechanism you find undesired. But if if fits you… Still I'd rather get used to the issue you described than give up `bash-completion`; even if I had noticed the issue. I have never noticed it though and the "why?" questions from [xenoid's comment](https://superuser.com/q/1514437/432690#comment2291686_1514437) could come from me as well.